# SQLServer msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail not sending email but query is executing

Tags: sql-server, email, html-email

I am trying to send an email on SQL Server using

```
            If @emailrec IS NOT NULL
            begin
                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                    @recipients = 'testemail@gmail.com', 
                    @subject = @emailrec, 
                    @body = @body, 
                    @body_format='HTML', 
                    @reply_to = 'noreply@myserver.com';
            end
```

The query is running successfully and the mail is getting queued in the messages. However I am not receiving anything in my email. How do I fix this so that I do receive the email?

Comment: What's the status of the mail item in `msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems`?

Comment: Also, are you intentionally missing out the parameter `@profile_name`?

Comment: Agreed @Larnu. I didn't see that part, i only read the query is running successfully. My bad.

Comment: Seems the OP has "left"...

Comment: @Larnu sorry for the late response, was caught up with other things. in the database mail log, I come across the error "The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server." And the reason why I am leaving off the profile_name is because I have a set default profile.

Comment: Ok, well the error is pretty explicit there, the SQL Server can't connect to your mail server. I would check the connectivity between your SQL Server and your mail server, and also check that the name of the server is correct.

Comment: @Larnu I'm now coming across another error stating "exception message: Cannot send mails to mail server (The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated." Is this staing that I am providing the wrong password for this email?

Comment: My knowledge of SMTP is limited I'm afraid. What has your favourite search engine suggested?

Answer (score -2):

Try checking your spam folder.